# How do you get Client's IP address? (Spring WebFlux WebSocket)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

As the title says, how do you obtain the details of the connection so to speak. Is there a way to get it through the WebSocketSession? I feel like I am missing something...

I need a way in order to ban ip addresses of bad users and also I wanted to display all users who are online on a map (like a dot on a map). I don't need help with the later I need help with getting a client's IP address.

I am using Spring's WebFlux WebSocket.

EDIT: I created a feature request : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Servlet-based `WebSocketSession` object does provide that information. This seems to be missing from the reactive flavor.

You should create a [Spring Framework issue to request this as an enhancement](https://jira.spring.io/).

Answer (score 0):

WebSocketSession has a method called getRemoteAddress(), you can get the remote address using any of its implemetation.

Comment: However, note that the remote address you get is not necessarily the address of the actual client.  That could be unobtainable.

Comment: The regular WebSocketSession has that as a method but reactive (WebFlux) WebSocket doesn't seem to have that method.

import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketSession;

Answer (score 0):

you can find ip address using HttpServletRequest for example

```
 String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
    String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
    if (remoteAddr.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")) {
        InetAddress localip = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        remoteAddr = localip.getHostAddress();
        remoteHost = localip.getHostName();
    }
```

Comment: the reactive websocket support is not exposing any servlet-related API; you're probably mixing things with the servlet-based websocket support.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(ServerRequest request) {
    String remoteAddr = request.remoteAddress().get().getAddress().getHostAddress());

    return null;
}
```